# How to add messages to recyclerview from last position to first?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, chat

I have a chat application. I want to receive messages from the server with packages containing 20 messages...

- I first saved the position of the messages in `recyclerview` along
  with each message in the server database.
- and for example when my `chatActivity` opens first i get messages from
  position `30 to 10` and put them in their position.

Have a suggestion to fetch the previous messages from the server?(like telegram)

i get this error because my recycler size is 0 at the first.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 30, Size: 0

Comment: It would be helpful if you share code snippet of your application.

Comment: You need to return 0 in getItemCount() if your list is empty. Just give a check in the function in your recyclerview

Comment: @FutureJJ i have a `recyclerview` with an adapter and model and view holder... 
  `msgDtoList.add(messages.get(i).getMsgPos(), msgDto);
                chatAppMsgAdapter.notifyItemInserted(messages.get(i).getMsgPos());
                msgRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.get(i).getMsgPos());`

Comment: @JaswantSingh I do not understand what you mean. Initially, the message list is empty. I get messages from the server from 30 to 10, and I want to place them in the position of thirty to ten. But because the list is empty, Error is given